# Blur Effectの取り外し方について

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

SwiftのBlurの取り外し方について質問です。

以下のcodeでPopUp Viewが取り外された時と同時に
ButtonでかけたBlur Effectを外したいと考えております。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

/* PopUp View */
@IBOutlet var addItemView: UIView!

/* Backgounrd Image */
@IBOutlet weak var backgoundImg: UIImageView!

/* Blur Effect */
@IBAction func BlurEffect(_ sender: Any) {


    /* setting of addItemView */
    addItemView.center = self.view.center


    /* Setting of Animation */
    self.backgoundImg.addBlurEffect() /* Blur */
    addItemView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    addItemView.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.view.addSubview(self.addItemView)
        self.addItemView.alpha = 1
        self.addItemView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }


}

/* I want to remove blur effect */
@IBAction func removeBlurEffect(_ sender: Any) {

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.addItemView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.addItemView.alpha = 0

}) { (success:Bool) in

    self.addItemView.removeFromSuperview()

    }

}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addItemView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()



}


}

extension UIImageView
{

func addBlurEffect(){

let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.addSubview(blurEffectView)

    }

}
```

extension関数でかけたBlurを取り外すにはどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか。

GitHubのURLは以下のようになります。
https://github.com/TakanoriHasebe/udemy-questions/tree/master/SwiftBlurEffect

わかるかたよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Extensionを利用して、`UIImageView`にBlurをかけるメソッドを追加したのなら、やはりExtensionにBlurを外すメソッドを定義するのが、考え方として自然です。

```
extension UIImageView {

    func addBlurEffect() {
        ....（省略）....
    }

    func removeBlurEffect() {
        // UIImageViewのsubviewすべてに対して、
        self.subviews.forEach{
        // 型をUIVisualEffectViewにキャストできる、すなわち型がUIVisualEffectViewであるsubviewは、
        if let effectView = $0 as? UIVisualEffectView {
            // superviewから取り外す。
            effectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}
```

Blurをかけるのに`backgoundImg.addBlurEffect()`を実行したのと同様に、`backgoundImg.removeBlurEffect()`を実行して、Blurを外せます。

---

> Blurを取り外すにはどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか。

それを知るのは、Blurを適用するのに、どういうことを実行したのかを調べることです。その逆を行えばいいのではないか？これまた自然な考え方です。
`self.addSubview(blurEffectView)`と、`UIImageView`に`addSubview()`することでBlurをかけたのですから、`removeFromSuperview()`すれば、Blurを外せるのではないかと、仮説が立てられます。あとはそれを検証するだけです。

---

```
CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
```

イニシアライザの書式は特別で、一般のメソッド（関数）の書式と区別してください。

```
init(scaleX:y:)
```

リファレンスにこのように掲載してあったら、

```
CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
```

と記述します。

Comment: 実装を行うことができました。
わかり易いご回答ありがとうございます。
また他の部分の指摘もありがとうございます。
何かありましたら、またよろしくお願いいたします。